# lualatex breaks after update to texlive 2016

Tags: luatex, texlive, koma-script, typearea

After I install the texlive 2016 (schema full), I got the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

by compiling the code below with lualatex::

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

There is no problem with pdflatex. 
Hast my file an error, or must I search the error elsewhere?

Comment: You need to add the instruction `\usepackage{luatex85}` to the preamble.

Comment: That's a small (known) bug in typearea. You can use as a workaround the class option pagesize= false to avoid the error message.

Comment: Use the `koma-script` version from the KOMA repository: see 
http://www.komascript.de/aktuellePakete  how one can add that repository for TeXLive.